# I'm confused about Sqlite comparisons on a text column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've got an Sqlite database where one of the columns is defined as "TEXT NOT NULL". Some of the values are strings and some can be cast to a DOUBLE and some can be case to INTEGER. Once I've narrowed it down to DOUBLE values, I want to do a query that gets a range of data. Suppose my column is named "Value". Can I do this?

```
SELECT * FROM Tbl WHERE ... AND Value >= 23 AND Value < 42
```

Is that going to do some kind of ASCII comparison or a numeric comparison? INTEGER or REAL? Does the BETWEEN operator work the same way?

And what happens if I do this?

```
SELECT MAX(Value) FROM Tbl WHERE ...
```

Will it do string or integer or floating-point comparisons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is all explained in the [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) article. For example, the answer to the first portion of questions is

> An INTEGER or REAL value is less than any TEXT or BLOB value. When an INTEGER or REAL is compared to another INTEGER or REAL, a numerical comparison is performed.

This is why `SELECT 9 < '1'` and `SELECT 9 < '11'` both give `1` (true).

> The expression "a BETWEEN b AND c" is treated as two separate binary comparisons "a >= b AND a <= c"

The most important point to know is that column type is merely an annotation; SQLite is dynamically typed so each value can have any type.

Answer (score 0):

you cant convert text to integer or double so you wont be able to do what you want.

If the column were varchar you could have a chance by doing:

```
select * 
from Tbl 
WHERE     ISNUMERIC(Value ) = 1 --condition to avoid a conversion from string to int for example
and cast(value as integer) > 1 --rest of your conditions
```